# Robot Framework : Unable to add resource file "Import file not found"

Tags: robotframework

I have recently started looking into Robot Framework. I created a sample project structure and added a basic test. I wanted to test the working of resource file as well. I created a resource file and tried to import it in the test robot file but I continue to get "Import file not found"

1. I tried updating the extension of resource file to `.resource` as well as `.robot`
2. I moved the resource file into the same folder as my test file
3. Made sure there are no test cases in my resource file
4. Updated the reference path to resource file multiple times, tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448593/robot-framework-resource-file-not-found-error)

**Code :**
**Test File:**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    These tests are written to validate SFDC Object Creation
Library          SeleniumLibrary
Resource         resource_file.resource


*** Test Cases ***
Validate Account creation in SFDC
    User clicks on Account tab from Home Page
    User clicks on New Account
    User enters the required Account information
    User verifies account creation in SFDC

*** Keywords ***
User clicks on Account tab from Home Page
User clicks on New Account
User enters the required Account information
User verifies account creation in SFDC
```

**Resource File**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    This Robot File contains all the utility methods
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${sfdc_url}                 https://test.salesforce.com
${browser_name}             chrome
${username}                 //input[@type='email']
${password}                 //input[@type='password']
${login_btn}                //input[@id='Login']
${home_button}              //nav[@role='navigation']/descendant::*[text()='Home']


*** Keywords ***
User logs in successfully to SFDC Environment
    Open Browser                     ${sfdc_url}                ${browser_name}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${username}                30
    Input Text                       ${username}                myusername
    Input Password                   ${password}                mypassword
    Click Button                     ${login_btn}
    Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${home_button}             60
```

Directory Structure

```
venv
|
|
|__tests
|
|
|__resourceFiles
```

Comment: What does your project structure look like? In your code sample file `resource_file.resource` must be in the same folder as your test case. You must supply its relative path if you have it in a different folder. Maybe something like this: `Resource         ../resources/resource_file.resource`

Comment: Yes I have tried both the approaches above. Still I see the warning.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you add to your question exactly what kind of directory structure you have and the error message?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This seems to be working even with the warning. Not sure if this is a plugin / IDE issue but even with the warning the execution is referencing the keywords from resource file.

Comment: I have a different structure: directories venv, tests and resources are all on the same level.